# Unable to Create Date Object with Timezone Beside UTC in Lambda

Tags: node.js, date, datetime, lambda, momentjs

I have a Lambda written in Node.js. It's being passed an Americas/New-York timezone datetime string:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // Stub out the response object
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: ""
    };

    const thingAsString = event.body.date; //This is a date/time expressed in local time
    const thingAsObject = new Date(thingAsString); //This is the date/time with a TZ of UTC.

    console.log("Before: %s", thingAsString );
    console.log("After: %s", thingAsObject.toISOString());

    return response;
};
```

Problem is when I try to turn it into a date/time object, it assumes the timezone as UTC.

[image]

Is there a way to turn that into a date object where the timezone isn't immediately set to UTC?

I've tried some options with `moment` and `monent-timezone`, but I have the same problem:

```
const original_date_string = "2019/10/15 14:21:14";
const original_date_object = new Date(original_date_string);
const original_date_object_est = moment.tz(original_date_object, 'America/New_York');
console.log("Original: %s", original_date_string);
console.log("UTC: %s", original_date_object_est.utc().toISOString());
```

[image]

Comment: `2019/10/15 14:21:14` us non-standard date string. Expect other weird handling of it, as well.

Comment: I have no control over the date coming to me.

Comment: If it's coming in with a known format, then you can still parse it correctly by supplying the format in Moment or doing a custom parsing with vanilla Date objects.

Comment: Agree with @VLAZ. Demo in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the date format and timezone on creation like this...

```
const mtz = require('moment-timezone');
const moment = require('moment');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // Stub out the response object
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: ""
    };
    // 2019/10/15 14:21:14
    const thingAsString = event.body.date;
    const thingAsObject = moment.tz(thingAsString, "YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss", 'America/New_York');

    console.log(thingAsObject);
    console.log(thingAsObject.utc());

    return response;
};
```